# What Has Happened to My VS2022 Development Environment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Hi there something weird has happended to intellisense in my VS2022 development environment.  For example, if I refer to an object or enumerator, intellisense offers me a list of properties/methods completely unrelated to the object I am working with, the required properties are listed, its just that they are buried amongst completely unrelated stuff.

In addition, and probably related, when I put in exception handling as in for example:

```
 Try

 Catch ex as exception
 
 End Try
```

When I type 'as' a whole raft of what appears to be boilerplate code gets dumped in place of the code that I am writing, I then have to execute an undo to get back to the original code.

Can someone clarify what is happening here and perhaps suggest a solution.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Did you enable Intellicode (not to be confused with IntelliSense), by any chance?

Comment: Not sure what intellicode is.  What is the difference between Intellicode and Intellisense?  the thing is 'intelli' it certainly isn't at the moment, its just a RPITA.